# After 2 checkboxes i selected disable the rest

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

Im new to asp.net...
I have a checkboxlist with 6 checkboxes
when 2 i selected i wont the other to be disabled, and if 1 is unchecked i want all to be enabled again

This is my code in aspx

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" TabStop="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="10" Width="420px" onclick="javascript:CheckCheck();" Font-Size="X-Large">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Texas NL 10/10" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Texas NL 25/25" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Texas 50/50" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Omaha PL 10/10" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Omaha PL 25/25" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Omaha PL 50/50" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Please help

Comment: what are your tries?

Answer (score 0):

Hum, what a cute little problem!

You could remove the client side click, set autopostback = true, and then use this code:

```
Protected Sub CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' count number checked.

    Dim CheckCount As Integer

    For Each MyCheck As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
        If MyCheck.Selected Then
            CheckCount += 1
        End If
    Next

    If CheckCount = 2 Then
        ' disable all boxes except those checked
        For Each MyCheck As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
            If Not MyCheck.Selected Then
                MyCheck.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If CheckCount < 2 Then
        ' enable all check boxes
        For Each MyCheck As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
            MyCheck.Enabled = True
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

## Edit:

The post code works.

The markup I had was this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" TabStop="false" CellPadding="5" 
    CellSpacing="10" Width="420px"  Font-Size="X-Large"
    AutoPostBack="true"
    >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Texas NL 10/10" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Texas NL 25/25" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Texas 50/50" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Omaha PL 10/10" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Omaha PL 25/25" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Omaha PL 50/50" Value="" TabStop="false" TabIndex="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

so we right click on the check box list, display properties for checkbox list, click on lightning bolt for events,
and we have this:

[image]

And now we have the code stub, and code like this:

```
Protected Sub CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' count number checked.

    Dim CheckCount As Integer

    For Each MyCheck As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
        If MyCheck.Selected Then
            CheckCount += 1
        End If
    Next

    If CheckCount = 2 Then
        ' disable all boxes except those checked
        For Each MyCheck As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
            If Not MyCheck.Selected Then
                MyCheck.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If CheckCount < 2 Then
        ' enable all check boxes
        For Each MyCheck As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
            MyCheck.Enabled = True
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

YOU don't have to type in the protected sub - VS does and creates that for you.

I suggest you create  blank new test web page - and try the above.

It is a working code solution as posted.

## Edit2:

So the poster is using c# - so we need to write this code in c#, and not vb.net.

this code will work as c#:

```
    protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // count number checked.
        int CheckCount = 0;

        foreach (ListItem MyCheck in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (MyCheck.Selected)
                CheckCount++;
        }

        if (CheckCount == 2)
        {
            // disable all boxes except those checked
            foreach (ListItem MyCheck in CheckBoxList1.Items)
                if (!MyCheck.Selected)
                    MyCheck.Enabled = false;
        }

        if (CheckCount < 2)
        {
            foreach (ListItem MyCheck in CheckBoxList1.Items)
                MyCheck.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt like protected sub
Gets alot of underlined error

Comment: See my edit. You have to learn how to use Visual Studio first - try the above steps

Comment: If i add it like you  shown i get this
        protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: Right, but you don't have to type in protected void - VS does that for you. So enter the vb code inside of that stub, and it will now work. hover, your code stub looks like this is c# and not vb.net You did not tag your post as using c#, so I used vb.net. So VS should create the code stub for you - you don't type that part in, but only the above code inside of the code stub. So, I will post a c# code version. Next time, tag your post - we can't know or guess if you using c# or vb.net. My example code is vb.net - I'll post c# working code in the next few minutes.

Comment: Ok, see in my post Edit #2 - I posted a working c# version. As noted, in the future, make sure you tag your question as vb.net, or c#. (or leave it out if you don't care, and are able to use either language).

Comment: aha i tag:ed it with asp.net will tag c# next time
Now it worked some...

If i click on the page next to the checkboxlist it will enable all the boxes again, but i can only select 2 of them
If i wont to change my choise i must click next to the checkboxlist to be able to unselect 1 
hope you understand what i mean

Comment: new problem, different question. You must have some other events, or code that causes a post back or something else that runs when you click else where. Maybe stray code from testing. But other controls, or even other buttons that cause a post-back should not effect or change or enable the checkbox list for no reason just out of the blue for no reason. If you have this working, then start a new question with your example working code, and explain the new problem.

Comment: Ok, last thing
when 2 is selected all boxes being disabled, also the 2 that is selected so i cant change my choice, is it possible to get it to work like i described?

Comment: then you have some other code messing this up. The post code lets you select 2 text boxes. At that point you can't select anymore. You have to un-check one of the two text boxes, and then all are re-enabled. So you must have somthing else. I would create a new blank test web page, and try with JUST the above markup and code. It works. If you select 2 - then the two remain enabled, and all others are disabled. You have to un-check one of those two, and then all boxes are now re-enabled, and you are free to choose any other check box.

Comment: Thanks
Looks like it i some javascript i use 
I have them for disabling all controls until my textbox has value
But looks like it doesnt work like i want
I will start over, your code works fine

Comment: I mean, this code would be possible client side - but it not clear if that is worth the effort. and if you don't want a whole page post-back, then put that checkbox list inside of a update panel, and you get quite much a JavaScript effect and operation anyway. Like all things, you have to decide how much efforts for the given results.  So, if the auto post back is less desirable, then wrap it in a update panel - you not get a full page post back as a result.